# NxN python arrays subsets

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I need to carry out some operation on a subset of an `NxN array`. I have the center of the sub-array, `x` and `y`, and its size.

So I can easily do:

`subset = data[y-size:y+size,x-size:x+size]`

And this is fine.

What I ask is if there is the possibility to do the same without writing an explicit loop if `x` and `y` are both 1D arrays of positions.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple example of a 5x5 array and setting *size=1* we can get:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))

size = 1
x = np.array([1,4])
y = np.array([1,4])
subsets = [data[j-size:j+size,i-size:i+size] for i in x for j in y]

print(subsets)
```

Which returns a list of numpy arrays:

```
[array([[0, 1],[5, 6]]),
 array([[15, 16],[20, 21]]),
 array([[3, 4],[8, 9]]),
 array([[18, 19],[23, 24]])]
```

Which I hope is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this and the previous answer definitely work (thanks!). However I was wondering is there is some sort of numpy method to make this operation faster. Let's assume, for instance, that I need to compute an average for each subset. And I did hope something like np.mean(data[y-size:y+size,x-size:x+size]) could give me back an array of results. But, of course, this does not work.

Comment: An average of each of the subsets above can simply be calculated by:'subset_ave = [np.mean(sub) for sub in subsets]' which returns a list of the averages (means)

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of subset assuming you have the list of positions `xList` and `yList`, this will do the tric:

```
subsetList = [ data[y-size:y+size,x-size:x+size] for x,y in zip(xList,yList) ]
```